# How can I create a helper that will take tags and put into links in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I am using acts_as_taggable_on, and everytime I want to display tags, I use the following:

```
  7     #tags
  8       %label Tags:
  9       - @vendor.tags.each do |tag|
 10         = link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name)
```

I have different models that all have tags, so ideally it would be a single helper that I pass the resource to...thinking *something* to do with using content_tag and a block....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper to display tags.

```
#tag_helper.rb
def display_tags(tags)
  tag_string = ""
  tags.each do |tag|
    tag_string << link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name)
  end
  tag_string.html_safe
end

#view.html.erb
=display_tags(@vendor.tags)
```

Comment: @dombesz -- I get an error at tag_string << link_to tag.name -- I don't think it likes the helper

Comment: @Angela whats the error? maybe you can try to use parantheses. `link_to(tag.name, tag_path(tag.name))`, the helper file should know about the helpers.

Comment: @dombesz -- says looking for {...shouldn't this use content_tag somehow?

Comment: @Angela It should work, what is the error message that you get?

Comment: @dombesz, let me try again and see, I think it's een getting an error processing the link_to, it's not treating it as a helper